# How do neural networks handle large images where the area of interest is small?

Tags: neural-network

If I've understood correctly, when training neural networks to recognize objects in images it's common to map single pixel to a single input layer node. However, sometimes we might have a large picture with only a small area of interest. For example, if we're training a neural net to recognize traffic signs, we might have images where the traffic sign covers only a small portion of it, while the rest is taken by the road, trees, sky etc. Creating a neural net which tries to find a traffic sign from every position seems extremely expensive.

My question is, are there any specific strategies to handle these sort of situations with neural networks, apart from preprocessing the image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 1 pixel per input node is usually **not** done. What enters your network is the feature vector and as such you should input actual *features*, not raw data. Inputing raw data (with all its noise) will not only lead to bad classification but training will take longer than necessary.

In short: preprocessing is unavoidable. You need a more abstract representation of your data. There are hundreds of ways to deal with the problem you're asking. Let me give you some popular approaches.

1) Image proccessing to find regions of interest. 
When detecting traffic signs a common strategy is to use edge detection (i.e. convolution with some filter), apply some heuristics, use a threshold filter and isolate regions of interest (blobs, strongly connected components etc) which are taken as input to the network.

2) Applying features without any prior knowledge or image processing. 
[Viola/Jones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework) use a specific image representation, from which they can compute features in a very fast way. Their framework has been shown to work in real-time. (I know their original work doesn't state NNs but I applied their features to Multilayer Perceptrons in my thesis, so you can use it with any classifier, really.)

3) Deep Learning. 
Learning better representations of the data can be incorporated into the neural network itself. These approaches are amongst the most popular researched atm. Since this is a very large topic, I can only give you some keywords so that you can research it on your own. [Autoencoders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) are networks that learn efficient representations. It is possible to use them with conventional ANNs. [Convolutional Neural Networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) seem a bit sophisticated at first sight but they are worth checking out. Before the actual classification of a neural network, they have alternating layers of subwindow convolution (edge detection) and resampling. CNNs are currently able to achieve some of the best results in OCR.

In every scenario you have to ask yourself: Am I 1) giving my ANN a representation that has all the data it needs to do the job (a representation that is not too abstract) and 2) keeping too much noise away (and thus staying abstract enough).

Comment: Found your brilliant answer after a long time! In 1), you mentioned "apply some heuristics", can you please give an example for those? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We usually dont use fully connected network to deal with image because the number of units in the input layer will be huge. In neural network, we have specific neural network to deal with image which is Convolutional neural network(CNN). 
However, CNN plays a role of feature extractor. The encoded feature will finally feed into a fully connected network which act as a classifier. In your case, I dont know how small your object is compare to the full image. But if the interested object is really small, even use CNN, the performance for image classification wont be very good. Then we probably need to use object detection(which used sliding window) to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want recognize small objects on large sized image, you should use "scanning window".

For "scanning window" you can to apply dimention reducing methods:

1. DCT (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform)
2. PCA (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So is it usual to handle these type of situations "outside" of neural nets by using a scanning window and giving the image from the scanning window to the net? Would it be completely impossible to think something like this could be handled by the neural net itself?

Comment: Example:
Let's take original image of 2000x2000 pixels. Scanning window may be 20x20 pixels (chosen empirically). In this case input layer for NN should contain 400 neurons, but if we apply DCT/PCA method to our scanning window, we can reduce to ~100 neurons.